# ConcurrentHashMap Conditional Replace

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I'd like to be able to conditionally replace a value in a ConcurrentHashMap.  That is, given:

```
public class PriceTick {
   final String instrumentId;
   ...
   final long timestamp;
   ...
```

And a class (let's call it TickHolder) which owns a ConcurrentHashMap (let's just call it *map*).

I wish to be able to implement a conditional put method, so that if there's no entry for the key, the new one is inserted, but if there is an existing entry, the new one is inserted **only if the timestamp value in the new PriceTick is greater than the existing one**.

For an old-school HashMap solution, TickHolder would have a put method:

```
public void add(PriceTick tick) {
   synchronized(map) {
      if ((map.get(tick.instrumentId) == null)
         || (tick.getTimestamp() > map.get(tick.instrumentId).getTimestamp()) )
         map.put(tick.instrumentId, tick);
      }
}
```

With a ConcurrentHashMap, one would want to drop the synchronization and use some atomic method like replace, but that's unconditional.  So clearly the "conditional replace" method must be written.

However, since the test-and-replace operation is non-atomic, in order to be thread safe, it would have to be synchronized - but my initial reading of the ConcurrentHashMap source leads me to think that external synchronization and their internal locks will not work very well, so at a very minimum, every Map method which performs structural changes and the containing class performs would have to be synchronized by the containing class... and even then, I'm going to be fairly uneasy.

I thought about subclassing ConcurrentHashMap, but that seems to be impossible.  It makes use of an inner final class HashEntry with default access, so although ConcurrentHashMap is not final, it's not extensible.

Which seems to mean that I have to fall back to implementing TickHolder as containing an old-school HashMap in order to write my conditional replace method.

So, the questions:  am I right about the above?  Have I (hopefully) missed something, whether obvious or subtle, which would lead to a different conclusion?  I'd really like to be able to make use of that lovely striped locking mechanism here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cletus solution formed the base for my solution to an almost identical problem. I think a couple of changes are needed though as if oldTick is null then replace throws a NullPointerException as stated by @hotzen

```
PriceTick oldTick;
do {
  oldTick = map.putIfAbsent(newTick.getInstrumentId());
} while (oldTick != null && oldTick.before(newTick) && !map.replace(newTick.getInstrumentId(), oldTick, newTick);
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution of cletus? Because I don't see why you would have a `NullPointerException`. The solution use `||` and `&&` so if `oldTick` is null, every right side of both expression will not be executed, preventing any `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Rob is correct.  With Cletus's solution as written, the first call to add will cause a NullPointerException.  I encountered that back when I first saw the answer, made my changes in my project, but never revisted this thread.

Comment: @CPerkins Thanks for the update! I don't quite understand what's wrong but I haven't tested the code either.

Comment: @Marc-Andre if oldTick is null, that satisfies the `oldTick == null` side of the `(oldTick == null || oldTick.before(newTick))`, so we proceed across the `&&` to the map.replace, which explicitly checks and throws a NullPointerException if oldTick or newTick are null. And since we're not supposed to have conversations in comments, I'm stopping now.

Comment: `((oldTick == null || oldTick.before(newTick)) && !map.replace())` if `oldTick == null` we have `((true) && !map.replace()`. Normally if you have true on the left side of `&&` it should not execute the right side (or I need some sleep because I'm forgetting some basics). But as you said we should not chat and I'll do some testing myself. (I'm probably just overlooking the replace since I've never used it)

Answer (score 4):

The non-deterministic solution is to loop [`replace()`](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#replace(K,%20V,%20V)):

```
do {
  PriceTick oldTick = map.get(newTick.getInstrumentId());
} while ((oldTick == null || oldTick.before(newTick)) && !map.replace(newTick.getInstrumentId(), oldTick, newTick);
```

Odd though it may seem, that is a commonly suggested pattern for this kind of thing.

Comment: Interesting.  When you say "non-deterministic", are you saying that the outcome is non-deterministic?  Or that the timing is?  Also, am I right that your "before" method is meant to stand for my timestamp comparison?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: By non-deterministic I mean that it may take several iterations to do the replacement because the get and replace obviously isn't an atomic operation but it is safe.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  A deterministic outcome from a non-deterministic method (with obviously non-deterministic timing).  Reminds me of TCP/IP. :)  Thanks, great idea.

Comment: Replace does not allow oldTick to be null, so this solution should directly go into a NullPointerException by replace when it is tried to replace the oldTick==null with newTick...

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer should be

```java
PriceTick oldTick;
do {
  oldTick = map.putIfAbsent(newTick.getInstrumentId(), newTick);
  if (oldTick == null) {
    break;
  }
} while (oldTick.before(newTick) && !map.replace(newTick.getInstrumentId(), oldTick, newTick);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, could you create a TickHolder class, and use that as the value in your map?  It makes the map slightly more cumbersome to use (getting a value is now map.getValue(key).getTick()), but it lets you keep the ConcurrentHashMap's behavior.

```
public class TickHolder {
  public PriceTick getTick() { /* returns current value */
  public synchronized PriceTick replaceIfNewer (PriceTick pCandidate) { /* does your check */ }
}
```

And your put method becomes something like:

```
public void updateTick (PriceTick pTick) {
  TickHolder value = map.getValue(pTick.getInstrumentId());
  if (value != null) {
    TickHolder newTick = new TickHolder(pTick);
    value = map.putIfAbsent(pTick.getInstrumentId(), newTick);
    if (value == null) {
      value = newTick;
    }
  }
  value.replaceIfNewer(pTick);
}
```

Comment: Interesting.    Did you mean to synchronize PriceTick?  How does that synchronization play with the locking mechanism inside ConcurentHashMap?

Comment: TickHolder.replaceIfNewer would need to be synchronized - that's basically where your atomic test-and-conditionally-update operation goes.  
There's no direct interaction between the synchronization on TickHolder.replaceIfNewer and the map's synchronization.  The map (with the little bit of logic in updateTick) makes sure there's never more than one TickHolder for a given key; the replaceIfNewer synchronization makes sure that updates to a given TickHolder don't have threading issues.
Neither updateTick nor PriceTick itself (assuming PriceTick is immutable) would need any other synchronization

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you think there's no need for other synchronization.  The synchronization of replaceIfNewer only limits calls to that method.  So other threads can make structural changes to the map using other methods, no?  Still, it's an interesting approach.  I will think on it later.

Comment: I guess I was making an implicit assumption that nothing ever gets removed from your map - all writes go through updateTick.  In which case, once you've gotten the TickHolder for a given InstrumentId, you no longer care about other structural changes to the map; the TickHolder you have is the value in the Map for your InstrumentId, and you just need your operation to be mutually exclusive with other operations on that InstrumentId.

Comment: Ticks do have to be removed, though I didn't say that.  Note, though, that it's not just removals - adds also can cause structural changes (e.g., rebucketing).